# Как вытянуть значение alt?

Tags: python, парсер, lxml, urllib

Пользуюсь библиотеками lxml и urllib, нужно альтернативный ответ решения уравнения, он находится в тэге , в атрибуте alt='то что мне нужно', как мне достать это значение? [image: вот собственно и скрин]

Comment: может через re?

Comment: ещё не знаком с регулярными выражениями

Comment: ну тут банальный парсинг строки, особо другого пути тут я не вижу, да и ре не сильно сложная тема - https://regex101.com/  вот отличный сайт для проверки регулярок

Comment: `bs4 `with `lxml`